# How to reduce the default size(height of a item) of a Combo box in SWT?

Tags: java, combobox, height, swt, size

The size of the combo box I created by swt has a fixed size(height of a item cannot be changed). Is there any way to change this default height.? Even thought I tried by reducing the font size of items, but no success.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you cannot explicitly set the height of a combo item.

Like all SWT widgets, the Combo box uses the native widget of the OS/Window system and hence is restricted to the respecive widgets capabilities. On Windows the item height adapts to the font size

`combo.setFont( new Font( combo.getDisplay(), "Arial", 27, SWT.NONE ) );`
[image: Combo with arge font]

`combo.setFont( new Font( combo.getDisplay(), "Arial", 7, SWT.NONE ) );`
[image: Combo with small font]

But other platforms may only adapt to a certain degree or not adapt at all.

Comment: What about in linux? It seems that in linux the minimum(smallest) size is fixed and not adaptable.

Comment: I don't run on Linux, thus I cant tell. Are you running on Linux? Does the item heigh change at all? What font size did you try?

Comment: I can confirm that it works on Linux Mint: [Font size 7](http://i.imgur.com/HEEdDly.png), [font size 27](http://i.imgur.com/J2xbonq.png).

Comment: @Hermann- I run on linux ubuntu 12.04 and reducing font size didn't work

Comment: @Baz - Are those examples are SWT combo examples??

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga Yes they are.